# Не правильно работает кнопка PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout, qpushbutton

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки выводилось значение ячейки.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
            # Таблица
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)            
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))                    
            # Инициализацтя экрана вкладок
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab1.layout_1   = QHBoxLayout(self.tab1)
            # Добавление таблицы на вкладку 1
        self.tab1.layout_1.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
            # Кнопка печати
        self.pushButton_print = QPushButton("Печать")
        self.tab1.layout_1.layout_1_1 = QVBoxLayout(self.tab1)                
            # Добавление вкладки
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "tab_1")            
            # Добавляем кнопку на вкладку            
        self.tab1.layout_1.addWidget(self.pushButton_print)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # Размещаем виджеты
        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)            
        self.widget1.pushButton_print.clicked.connect(self.on_click_print) 

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)                
    
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget1)
        
    def on_click_print(self):                            
        print("Печать")            
        print(MyWidget.tableWidget.itemAt(0, 0).text())

    def clear(self):
        self.tableWidget.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("PyQt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Замените `MyWidget.tableWidget...` на `self.widget1.tableWidget...` ,это первое. Второе - у меня клик на кнопку работает и все выводится )

Comment: А за что на такой вопрос 2 за?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно будет так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)            
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Cell (1,1)"))            

        self.pushButton_print = QPushButton("Печать")        

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        
        self.tab1 = QWidget()

#        self.tab1.layout_1   = QHBoxLayout(self.tab1)
        self.tab1_layout   = QHBoxLayout(self.tab1)
        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
# ???        self.tab1.layout_1.layout_1_1 = QVBoxLayout(self.tab1) 
        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_print)
 
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "tab_1") 
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        
        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)   

        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)            
        self.widget1.pushButton_print.clicked.connect(self.on_click_print)         
    
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget1)
        
    def on_click_print(self):                            
#        print("Печать")            
#        print(MyWidget.tableWidget.itemAt(0, 0).text())
        print(self.widget1.tableWidget.itemAt(0, 0).text())

    def clear(self):
        self.tableWidget.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("PyQt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]